# What problems could I check for with a low-pressure dishwasher pump?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

I have a GE Potscrubber 850 dishwasher that is not washing dishes (no water comes out during cycle). Here is what I have tried:

I cleaned out the float valve, and it appears to be functioning.

I took off the sump grate and noticed no excessive amount of sludge/goo/crap in it.

I pried off the washing arms and looked to clean them, but nothing was clogging them.

When I fake latch the door and start the cycle (exhilerating and risky, I know) what I see is a sudden burst of full strength water coming out where the washing arms were attached, then a very small flow afterwards (that only dribbled up, with no height being gained). The first spray lasts half a second and almost hits the roof of the dishwasher (proper pressure).

What else could I check on my own before calling a plumber/repairperson?

Thanks for any insights!